# Create user in Keycloak rest api custom logic

Tags: java, keycloak, registration

We create users with rest api in Keycloak. Before creating a user (immediately after receiving the creation data), we need keycloak go to our service and decrypt the login and password, which transfer encypted . After received a response with decrypted data it can create user. How can we add such functionality to the keycloak code and where should it be done?

Custom registration flow works only with self registration(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.